# DB2 - increment CURRENT_DATE

Tags: sql, date, db2

I'm just trying to set the expire_date_membership to a date that is going to be 2 years after the current date, but don't seam to get the syntax right.
Can someone help?

```
CREATE TABLE Members (
   pid INTEGER NOT NULL, 
   registration_date_membership DATE DEFAULT CURRENT_DATE, 
   expire_date_membership DATE DEFAULT (CURRENT_DATE + 24 MONTHS), 
   membership_fees DOUBLE, 
   overdue_fees DOUBLE, 
   PRIMARY KEY(pid),
   FOREIGN KEY (pid) REFERENCES Person)
```

Error message:

> DB21034E  The command was processed as an SQL statement because it was
>   not a  valid Command Line Processor command.  During SQL processing it
>   returned: SQL0104N  An unexpected token "DEFAULT" was found following
>   "ate_memebership  DATE".  Expected tokens may include:  "CHECK". 
>   SQLSTATE=42601

Answer (score 2):

You're missing WITH keyword.

Your query should be :

```
CREATE TABLE Members (
   pid INTEGER NOT NULL, 
   registration_date_membership DATE WITH DEFAULT CURRENT_DATE, 
   expire_date_membership DATE WITH DEFAULT (CURRENT_DATE + 24 MONTHS), 
   membership_fees DOUBLE, 
   overdue_fees DOUBLE, 
   PRIMARY KEY(pid),
   FOREIGN KEY (pid) REFERENCES Person)
```

More : [Default values](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/dzichelp/v2r2/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2z10.doc.intro/src/tpc/db2z_defaultvalues.htm)

Comment: DB21034E  The command was processed as an SQL statement because it was not a 
valid Command Line Processor command.  During SQL processing it returned:
SQL0104N  An unexpected token "(" was found following "ip DATE WITH DEFAULT".  
Expected tokens may include:  "CHECK".  SQLSTATE=42601

Comment: try to use this :  expire_date_membership DATE WITH DEFAULT CURRENT_DATE + 24 MONTHS,

Comment: already tried ... still saying Expected tokens may include:  "<space>".

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help you, but instead of DATE datatype, it has changed to TIMESTAMP.

> registration_date_membership **TIMESTAMP** WITH DEFAULT **CURRENT TIMESTAMP**, 
>       expire_date_membership **TIMESTAMP** WITH DEFAULT **TIMESTAMPADD(256,40,TIMESTAMP((CURRENT TIMESTAMP**)),